# Разбить список по 4 элемента и посчитать количество уникальных

Tags: java, arraylist

Есть список `listmain`, кратный 4. Нужно из него получить уникальные списки `listN` по 4 элемента и их количество `countlistN`.

Списки из 4 элементов формируются по определенным правилам

```
listN(3)=listmain(0)
listN(0)=listmain(1) 
listN(1)=listmain(2)    
listN(2)=listmain(3)
listN(3)=listmain(4)
listN(0)=listmain(5)
listN(1)=listmain(6)
listN(2)=listmain(7)
...
listN(3)=listmain(i)
listN(0)=listmain(i+1)
listN(1)=listmain(i+2)
listN(2)=listmain(i+3)
```

**Пример**

```
listmain {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4}
```

должны получить

```
list1 [2, 3, 4, 1]
countlist1 = 2
list2 [6, 7, 8, 5]
countlist1 = 1
```

Придумал следующий алгоритм

1. Исходный список заполняем в `ArrayList` `listmain`
2. Создаем нужное количество списков по 4 элемента и заполняем их (чтоб можно было сделать set)
3. Перебираем `listmain` по 4 элемента и заменяем значения в созданных списках по 4 элемента и считаем их количество

   ```
   int count1 = 0;  
   int i = 0;  
   int j = 0;  
   for (i = 0; i < listmain.size(); i = i+4) {  
       list1.set(j+3,listmain.get(i));  
       list1.set(j,listmain.get(i+1));  
       list1.set(j+1,listmain.get(i+2));  
       list1.set(j+2,listmain.get(i+3));  
       if ((list1.containsAll(listN))&&(listN.containsAll(list1))){  
           count1++;  
       }  
   }
   ```

Но вопросов больше чем ответов.

1. Как программно создать `ArrayList`?

Т.е. я должен как-то написать, создай мне столько-то (`listmain.size())/4` новых `ArrayList` с таким-то именами, чтоб потом к ним можно было обращаться.

2. Как сравнить между собой все эти `ArrayList` по 4 элемента?

Создавать еще `ArrayList` и помещать в него как объекты `ArrayList` по 4 элемента? А потом?

Comment: Следуя вашему примеру, вы из `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4` должны получить `4123` и `8567` и т.д. а не `2341` .... в чем ошибка? ........`Как программно создать ArrayList` - ну сделайте лист листов) .........

Comment: Для этой задачи в качестве listN, на мой взгляд, лучше подойдет простой двумерный массив размера Nx4 и метод `Arrays.equals`.

Comment: 2341 - Это правильно. вот код для проверки - [ссылка](http://ideone.com/cylNZe)

Comment: @rezhisser ну как скажите)  ответ я вам дал.....вроде объяснил что как....... под себя можно исправить на `listOfNums.add(list.get(i + 1));
            listOfNums.add(list.get(i + 2));
            listOfNums.add(list.get(i + 3));
            listOfNums.add(list.get(i));`  ......ссылка на рабочий код есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить "динамически" несколько `ArrayList` не обязательно их создавать через `new`, достаточно просто завести еще один лист, с типом `ArrayList<Integer>`, т.е.:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listArr = new ArrayList<>(тут размер);
```

итого получим как раз "массив" из `ArrayList<Integer>` размером, определенным выше:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4));
int listSize = list.size();

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listArr = new ArrayList<>(listSize/4);
```

Далее, вполне совершенно свободно заполняем эти списки через цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i += 4) {
    ArrayList<Integer> listOfNums = new ArrayList<>();

    listOfNums.add(list.get(i + 1));
    listOfNums.add(list.get(i + 2));
    listOfNums.add(list.get(i + 3));
    listOfNums.add(list.get(i));

    listArr.add(listOfNums);
}
```

т.е. создаем список, добавляем в него цифры в нужной последовательности и далее этот список вносим в наш "массив" списков.

В итоге на выходе получим

```
[[2, 3, 4, 1], [6, 7, 8, 5], [2, 3, 4, 1]]
```

А за подсчет количества уникальных элементов в коллекции вроде как отвечает метод [frequency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object))
из класса `Collections`. Т.е. если мы ему дадим на вход

```
list.add("Лилия");
list.add("Роза");
list.add("Лилия");
```

и напишем

```
Collections.frequency(list, "Лилия");
```

то он выведет число `2` (через `System.out.print`)

В итоге нужно просто этим воспользоваться:

```
Set<ArrayList<Integer>> uniqueSet = new HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>(listArr);

for (ArrayList<Integer> temp : uniqueSet) {
    System.out.println("counts of " + temp + ": " + Collections.frequency(listArr, temp));
}
```

выведет:

```
counts of [2, 3, 4, 1]: 2
counts of [6, 7, 8, 5]: 1
```

`HashSet`- тут для того чтобы в цикле пробежать только по уникальным значениям. Ведь мы знаем, что Set - это множество неповторяющихся значений

Пример целиком

```js
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4));
int listSize = list.size();

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listArr = new ArrayList<>(listSize/4);

for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i += 4) {
  ArrayList<Integer> listOfNums = new ArrayList<>();
  listOfNums.add(list.get(i + 3));
  listOfNums.add(list.get(i));
  listOfNums.add(list.get(i + 1));
  listOfNums.add(list.get(i + 2));
  listArr.add(listOfNums);
}

// Это чтоб пробежаться только по уникальным значениям листа.
Set<ArrayList<Integer>> uniqueSet = new HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>(listArr);

for (ArrayList<Integer> temp : uniqueSet) {
  System.out.println("counts of " + temp + ": " + Collections.frequency(listArr, temp));
}
```

Пример на внешнем ресурсе https://ideone.com/aNKfa2

Comment: Алексей, спасибо!

Comment: @rezhisser Если вам дали правильный ответ - проголосуйте за него\отметьте его верным ( серая галочка сбоку ответа). Это поможет другим понять, что ответ подошел для решения проблемы.